# Pycharm and remote interpreter (Docker) shows errors but runs fine

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, remote-debugging

I have set up a remote interpreter which uses a docker image containing anaconda and other packages. My python project then runs from this interpreter.

[image]

The code itself runs perfectly. The problem is Pycharm itself doesn't recognise that the packages are installed and believes there should be error, the same also applies for python functions such as min, max and tuple. Everything runs fine, however it makes reading the code a nightmare. (images below)

[image]
[image]

I'm running on Mac OS X El capitan 10.11.6, Pycharm Pro 2016.2.3 and Docker for Mac 1.12.1

Comment: Try to run "invalidate caches / restart" option from "file" menu

Comment: @Alex - worked a treat. Will write as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Alex above running the "invalidate caches / restart" option from "file" menu fixes the issues